# Twitter api doesn't send media element with timeline

Tags: node.js, api, twitter

So I am using the twitter node module and twitters rest api to fetch timelines.
All works well, except that attached images do not get sent with the response.
Even after I added "include_entities: true" to the options object.

I'm talking about an image directly attached to a twitter post, links get displayed just fine.

I simply can't find a way to get it to display, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Every tweet has a Media Entity attached to it. You need to find the Media Id and then get the URL from -mediaURL. The below picture shows the full object model.

[image]

PC : https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tutorials/rest-api-design-twitter-example.jsp

Comment: I am aware of that model. However, entities always has everything except the media object, even if the post clearly has a picture attached

Comment: Are you using the "tweet_mode=extended" parameter when the Tweet object shows "truncated: true"?